# In directx11 when I create vertexbuffer I have unhandled exception error

Tags: directx-11, unhandled-exception

```
//change directory
_chdir("Models");

std::ifstream InFile;
InFile.open(strFilename);
if (!InFile)
{
    MessageBox(0, L"file does not exist", 0, 0);
    return 0;
}

char strCommand[256] = { 0 };

for (;;)
{
    InFile >> strCommand;
    if (!InFile)
        break;

    if (0 == strcmp(strCommand, "#"))
    {
        // Comment
    }
    else if (0 == strcmp(strCommand, "v"))
    {
        // Vertex Position
        float x, y, z;
        InFile >> x >> y >> z;
        Positions->push_back(XMFLOAT3(x, y, z));
        mVCount++;
    }
    else if (0 == strcmp(strCommand, "vt"))
    {
        // Vertex TexCoord
        float u, v;
        InFile >> u >> v;
        TexCoords->push_back(XMFLOAT2(u, v));
        mTCount++;
    }
    else if (0 == strcmp(strCommand, "vn"))
    {
        // Vertex Normal
        float x, y, z;
        InFile >> x >> y >> z;
        Normals->push_back(XMFLOAT3(x, y, z));
        mNCount++;
    }
    else if (0 == strcmp(strCommand, "f"))
    {
        // Face
        UINT iPosition, iTexCoord, iNormal;
        VERTEX::objVertex vertex;

        for (UINT iFace = 0; iFace < 3; iFace++)
        {
            ZeroMemory(&vertex, sizeof(VERTEX::objVertex));

            // OBJ format uses 1-based arrays
            InFile >> iPosition;
            vertex.position = (*Positions)[iPosition - 1];
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            vIndices->push_back(iPosition - 1);
            mICount++;
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            if ('/' == InFile.peek())
            {
                InFile.ignore();

                if ('/' != InFile.peek())
                {
                    // Optional texture coordinate
                    InFile >> iTexCoord;
                    vertex.texcoord = (*TexCoords)[iTexCoord - 1];
                }

                if ('/' == InFile.peek())
                {
                    InFile.ignore();

                    // Optional vertex normal
                    InFile >> iNormal;
                    vertex.normal = (*Normals)[iNormal - 1];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //skip without vertex
    }

    //InFile.ignore(1000, '\n');
}

InFile.close();
_chdir("..");

return S_OK;
```

this is when i try to load geometry from .obj file.

```
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC vbd;
vbd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_IMMUTABLE;
vbd.ByteWidth = sizeof(VERTEX::objVertex) * mVCount;
vbd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
vbd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
vbd.MiscFlags = 0;
vbd.StructureByteStride = 0;

D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA vinitData;
vinitData.pSysMem = Positions;
HR(Device->CreateBuffer(&vbd, &vinitData, &pmVB));

D3D11_BUFFER_DESC ibd;
ibd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_IMMUTABLE;
ibd.ByteWidth = sizeof(UINT)* mICount;
ibd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;
ibd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
ibd.MiscFlags = 0;
D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA iinitData;
iinitData.pSysMem = vindices;
HR(Device->CreateBuffer(&ibd, &iinitData, &pmIB));

return S_OK;
```

and this is when i try to create buffer.
when i try to debug, vs said unhandled exception at HR() function.
i have this problem in most three days and i don't know why this happening. please give me some adivise.

Comment: First step of debugging Direct3D applications: Ensure that you care checking every ``HRESULT`` for failure, and try to enable the [debug device](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/11/30/direct3d-sdk-debug-layer-tricks.aspx) to look for error messages.

Comment: The initial data for the Vertex Buffer appears to come from a variable called "Positions". Given that you call ->push_back on that pointer, is it a pointer to a std::vector<XM_FLOAT3>?

If so, you can't pass a pointer to a std::vector to be your initial data, you need a pointer to the first element of the vector at the very least. Secondly, your vertices are presumably made up of more than just positions; you have texture coordinates and normals too. Unless your Vertex::obVertex is just a position, you're going to run out of data before it fills the entire vertex buffer.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn Thank you for reply. This code is inherited from d3dApp.h which is come from "introduction to d# game programming with directx 11 by frank luna" and i was looked that code and i think debug flags are on. but i'm sorry what you mean that checking every HRESTULT for failure. Can you give me some more explain it for me?

Comment: @AdamMiles Thank you for reply. vairable called "Positions" is vector<XMFLOAT3>. so you mean i have to call it "(&Positions)[0]" like this?
Secondly, you're right that .obj file's vertex has more variables, and my vertex struct has too. But i want to test in small modules. you mean that i have to full every variables to create vertex buffer?

Comment: If Positions is a pointer then you'll need &((*Positions)[0]); 
You can't only initialise the positions in your vertex buffer, you have to initialise all the data at once. Provide an array of VERTEX instead where each vertex has initialised positions but also space for the other vertex attributes (you can leave those uninitialised if you wish).

Comment: OMG. the code is working! oh, i can't believe this! i'm appricating with your help. i was suffered with this problem almost 3 days!! Thank you very much!! @AdamMiles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments, the solution was two-fold:

a) Passing a pointer to a std::vector is incorrect as the underlying data of a std::vector doesn't live at that address.

b) Once corrected, passing data that only contains the position attributes when trying to initialise a vertex buffer large enough to contain all the attributes will fail. D3D will try to read more data than the 'initial data' is providing and is likely the cause of the exception. The solution is to provide initial data that contains enough data for all attributes of all the vertices.